# Opera - driver.WindowHandles returns wrong count

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera

In my scenario, I'm verifying whether clicking on a link navigates to another page (verifying for the page title). **IE**, **FF** and **chrome** return 2 as expected but **Opera**  returns 4. I didn't have any other Opera instances opened at the time of running tests. It clicks on the link and required page is opened but WindowHandles returns 4.

**Code:**

```
string BaseWindow = Drivers._driverInstance.CurrentWindowHandle;
Drivers._driverInstance.SwitchTo().Frame(Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.ClassName("iframe-fix")));
if (Drivers._driverInstance.GetType().Name.ToString() == "InternetExplorerDriver")
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Drivers._driverInstance;
    js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.LinkText("Professional Services.")));
}
else
{
    Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.LinkText("Professional Services.")).Click();
}
    System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> handles = Drivers._driverInstance.WindowHandles;
    if (handles.Count == 2)
    {
      foreach (string handle in handles)
      {
         if (handle != BaseWindow)
         {
            string title = Drivers._driverInstance.SwitchTo().Window(handle).Title;
            Assert.AreEqual("title of the page", Drivers._driverInstance.Title);
          }
      }
     }
    else
    {
        Assert.Fail("WindowHandles returns " + handles.Count + " instead of 2");
    }
Drivers._driverInstance.SwitchTo().Window(BaseWindow);
```

Can someone suggest why Opera returns 4 instead of 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Opera driver doesn't return the right number of handles. This issue has already been reported to the project but it seems that the project is no longer maintained:

https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/issues/15

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is there any workaround to solve this? Thanks

Comment: I could run successfully on Chrome FF and IE. Test case fails in Opera only. Is there any work around to manage for the test case to pass in Opera as well. Can you please elaborate what do you mean by "Chrome itself makes a great workaround." @Florent B.

Comment: By suggesting Chrome as a workaround, I was suggesting to drop Opera. Opera represent only 1.3% of the market share and now uses the same engine as Chrome. So I'd say that the risk doesn't worth the effort. But if you don't have a choice, it may be possible to select the right handle among the 4.

Comment: Thank you Florent B. I'll just avoid this test case for Opera or as you suggested change my code to handle the right window. Thank  you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same thing as you with Opera driver, plus (if I remember it right), the `CurrentWindowHandle` property doesn't work either.

Workaround:

```
public static void SwitchToPopup(TestTarget target, bool toPopup)
{
    if (target.IsOpera)
    {
        if (toPopup)
        {
            _windowIndex += 3;
            new WebDriverWait(target.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DefaultTimeoutInSeconds)).Until(d => d.WindowHandles.Count > _windowIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            _windowIndex -= 3;
        }
        target.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(target.Driver.WindowHandles[_windowIndex]);
    }
    else
    {
        IEnumerable<string> windowHandles = toPopup ? target.Driver.WindowHandles : target.Driver.WindowHandles.Reverse();

        bool bFound = false;
        foreach (string windowHandle in windowHandles)
        {
            if (bFound)
            {
                target.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle);
                break;
            }
            bFound = windowHandle == target.Driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        }
    }
}
```