# Unable to switch to new tab in Chrome in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a issue while switching to new tab in chrome, by following some links on internet i came to know it is the issue with Chrome Driver, but i have latest chrome driver(2.21) and updated chrome browser(version 50).

Issue : unknown error: DevTools returned unknown type:webview

(After debugging, i get to know the issue is coming from driver.getWindowHandles();)

Pls help!!!

Comment: Please refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353057/opera-driver-windowhandles-returns-wrong-count/36356274#36356274). It might help.

Answer (score -1):

You should post the code that is giving error, nevertheless, below is the code that can be used to switch between chrome tabs:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
             "D:\\path\\to\\chrome\\exe\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
String currWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("t").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
// Open new tab
Set<String windowsList = driver.getWindowHandles();
for (String str : windowsList) {
   if (!str.equals(currWindow)) {
   driver.switchTo().window(str);
   }
}
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com"); // open facebook
```